# How to remove VLC Nightly Build?

Tags: 11.10, vlc

I would like to remove the VLC nightly build and go back to the default VLC player. I tried `sudo apt-get remove vlc` which removed it, then I deleted the Nightly PPA and tried to install VLC `sudo apt-get install vlc` but couldn't as I got a few errors.

There must a proper method, please let me know.

Comment: after removing ppa did you run "apt-get update"?

Comment: Yes I did run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper method to remove a ppa and to use the program version of the official ubuntu repos, is to use ppa-purge.

First, you need to install ppa-purge:

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

then, you purge the ppa you installed previously. (in your case vlc-daily)

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily`

This downgrades the vlc version from the daily version of the ppa to the stable version in the ubuntu universe repo.

Answer (score 3):

A vlc package install consists of at least 5 packages, typically at least 7. To switch from the ppa to repo vlc you should remove them all. From the cli it's pretty simple, 2 ways

Removing vlc-data will cause all the other vlc packages to be removed

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc-data
```

Or you can do this as long as you've never done a vlc source build installed with checkinstall

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc*
```

The former command will work fine

Answer (score 0):

remove completely vlc via synaptic and install vlc via synaptic

Comment: Synaptic is not a part of 11.10 :D

Answer (score 0):

Normally I should use the purge option to remove VLC completely. Mind in your home dir (use the ctrl+h keys) remove .config/vlc/vlcrc and .vlc/vlcrc also.